# Question about properties of matrix

Tags: matrices

Two matrices

$$\boldsymbol{R}(z) = \overline{\boldsymbol{B}(z)^\vphantom{1}}\,\overline{\boldsymbol{A}(z)^{-1}}, \quad \boldsymbol{T}(z) = \overline{\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(z)}$$

where the elements of $\boldsymbol{R}(z)$ and $\boldsymbol{T}(z)$ are uniformly bounded by $1$, where $\boldsymbol{A}(z), \boldsymbol{B}(z)$ are complex valued $2\times 2$ matrices and the overline denotes complex conjugate.

The matrices $\boldsymbol{A,B}$ also form another matrix which has the property

$$\boldsymbol{P} = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{A}(z)\quad \overline{\boldsymbol{B}(z)} \\ \boldsymbol{B}(z) \quad \overline{\boldsymbol{A}(z)}\end{bmatrix}, \quad \det{P} = 1.$$

My question is, can I deduce anything about matrices $\boldsymbol{A,B}$ from the boundedness of $\boldsymbol{R,T}$?

Comment: If the functions in $\boldsymbol T$ are continuous, you can low-bound the absolute value of the determinant as well. Are they?

Comment: Yes, functions are continuous in both.